# How to make dropright in sidebar?

Tags: html

I want to have dropright in the sidebar
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWqSP.jpg

I tried to copy the code from another site

```
<div class="slidedua" style="display: grid;max-height: 300px;">
    <a href="#" class="border-bottom border-right border-left">TV Mobil</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="123.html">123</a>
            <a href="321.html">321</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="border-bottom border-right border-left">Speaker Mobil</a>
    <a href="#" class="border-bottom border-right border-left">Lampu Mobil</a>
    <a href="#" class="border-bottom border-right border-left">Sarung Stir</a>
    <a href="#" class="border-bottom border-right border-left">Charger HP</a>
    <a href="#" class="border-bottom border-right border-left">Lainnya</a>
</div>
```

I want to have dropright like in this picture, and if I press "gaming headset" they will direct me to the "gaming headset page", I already have the page just want to know how to make the dropright and connect it to my page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `Multi Level Menu`
please visit https://codepen.io/ajaypatelaj/pen/prHjD

Answer (score 0):

Connect to other page read more about documentation [See example](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-links.php)

```
<a href="url">About</a> <!-- in URL put your folder name if not then leave it directly put your page name and end with .html like this  -->
```

Example 1 : If your file inside the folder and folder name like pages and inside pages folder about page is there then below code will help u

```
<a href="pages/about.html">About</a>
```

Example 2 : Without folder directly put your page name

This is your solution

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NavBar</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
           
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 1 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to edit then see Code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/6uLra79o/)